# BigQuery streaming insert with a function applied to another column

Tags: google-bigquery

When using client libraries I can pass a list of objects to be inserted into BigQuery, like this one in Go https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-table-insert-rows#bigquery_table_insert_rows-go

But what if I want to do something like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2)
VALUES
    ("a", FARM_FINGERPRINT("a")),
    ("bcd", FARM_FINGERPRINT("bcd")),
```

i.e. providing only values "a", "bcd" insert into both columns where one is just a function of another.

How to do this using streaming insert in Go library, for example? Like this pseudo-code:

```golang
...
inserter := client.Dataset(datasetID).Table(tableID).Inserter()
items := []*Item{
        // Item implements the ValueSaver interface.
        {Name: "Phred Phlyntstone", Age: 32, SomeColumn: 'CALL_ME("Phred Phlyntstone")'},
        {Name: "Wylma Phlyntstone", Age: 29, SomeColumn: 'CALL_ME("Wylma Phlyntstone")'}},
}
...
```

One possibility is to re-implement the function in Go code and insert in explicitly, but it's not ideal. Or with simple INSERT INTO I can hit DML limits. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based from the documentation it might not be possible to perform DML functions using `Inserter()`. [Inserter()](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery#Inserter) accepts either `Struct`, [StructSaver](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery#StructSaver) and [ValueSaver](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery#ValueSaver) as “src”.

`Struct` is made of key value pairs so whatever value assigned to those, that will be it. Type `StructSaver`  accepts Schema, InsertId and `Struct` as parameters. So basically it is just the same as passing a Struct but you can just pass on extra parameters. `ValueSaver` accepts Schema, InsertID and Row. [Row](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery#Value) is of type Value so it can accept any value with any data type. Based from the accepted types of Inserter(), they just all accept key value pairs and whatever the value of the key value pairs, that will be the data loaded.

Unfortunately, the best possible workaround for this is the suggestion that you have presented which is re-implementing the function in the code since it won't hit the DML limits. You can try creating a [feature request for Go lang](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/issues) to possibly implement this since it will be a cool feature to have.

Answer (score 0):

Both the legacy streaming API (e.g. the Go inserter you cited) and the newer storage write API allow insertion of values directly into a table.

This doesn't involve the query engine, so doing things like calling functions/UDFs/etc is not a possibility.

Another possibility: you could do something like construct a logical or materialized view that uses the table you're streaming data into as the base table.